# fetch hudi table properties in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hudi

I have created a HUDI table in AWS Glue using EMR.

I want to validate the index type and other properties in HUDI table. I tried checking in the schema but it is not available.

Is there a way to check the properties of created HUDI table?

Properties i want to see is: 1) index type 2) is metadata enabled.